# Is there way to use javascript to sychronize the server file with yours?

Tags: javascript, php, html

So that if i change a div with :

```
 <form>
Datum: <input type="text" id="datum">
</form> 

  <div id='test1'>This is a dummy text</div>
<a id="www" >Replace it!</a>

<script>

  var MyDiv1 = document.getElementById('datum');

document.getElementById("www").onclick = function() {


document.getElementById("test1").innerHTML = MyDiv1.value;  
};
</script>
```

Is it possible  to change it on the server right away instead of your local browser?
So not get reset with F5 Reload? And without using cookies?

Comment: Yes, that's called a Content Management System. There's plenty of them out there already.

Comment: Ajax. Have fun learning about it.

Comment: You can achieve this using Ajax and send data to your server without having to hit F5

Comment: Can someone help me out and show me how to do it? Thanks in advance  ^^